# Memory overflow in org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, websphere-8

I have WebSphere 8.0.0.7 application server with Spring(3.2.1)/Hibernate(4.1.9) application installed.
After several weeks of continuous work PROD stage failed due to Java heap overflow.
Analysis of PHD dominator tree shows the following:

[image: PHD dominator tree]

Looking at Hibernate sources I can't really understand where those char sequences may take place.
Internet gave me several similar leaks for older version of WebSphere, but they seems to be fixed the version I use.

Does anyone may help to understand a root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use MAT to analyze IBM dumps. IBM HeapAnalyzer shows better tree without strange memory consumers definition.